Integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\sin{x})^n (\cos{x})^m e^{ikx} dx$
I am looking for a reference of the following result:

\begin{align}
& \mbox{For positive integers}\quad
m,\ n,\ k,\ m + n < k,
\\[2mm] & \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cos^{m}\left(x\right)
\,{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}kx}\,\,{\rm d}x = 0
\end{align}


I have searched in the books:

Nouvelles tables d'intégrales définies $1867$
and Table of Integrals, Series, and Products by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik,



$\rule{1.6cm}{0pt}$but was unable to find it.

One way to prove this is by expanding power of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of the complex exponential.
This may also be in papers related to Fourier coefficients of powers of $\sin$ and $\cos$.


I don't think you actually need to expand sin and cosine in terms of complex exponentials, just acknowledge that they can be expanded into complex exponentials and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ik\theta}\ d\theta = 0$ for all non-zero integer $k.$  Then if $m+n < k$ indicates that if you were to expand what is above every term is a complex exponential that evaluates to 0.

I put it in $\tt Mathematica$ and I got a horrible expression which includes hypergeometric functions.

Yes, that is what I will write if I am unable to find a reference @user317176 .  This seems to be a trivial integral, a well explained proof spans to about 1/4 of a page, however, it would be nice to have a reference.

Did you put in the constraint that $m,n,k$ are positive integers? @FelixMarin

@Sam Yes. $\mbox{}$

then I am not sure why it's not simplifying the expression @FelixMarin

Another way is converting the integral to a contour integral on the unit circle by $z=e^{ix}$. The integral then becomes
$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^2-1)^n(z^2+1)^m}{2^{n+m}i^{n+1}z^{n+m+k+1}}dz.$$
It evaluates to $0$ by Residue theorem because $\frac{d^{n+m+k}}{dz^{n+m+k}}(z^2-1)^n(z^2+1)^m=0$ due to $k>m+n.$

Firstly,
$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi e^{ihx} dx=2\pi \delta_{k0},$$
where $\;\delta_{ij}\;$ is the Kronekker's symbol.
Production $\;\sin^n(x)\cos^m(x)\;$ has bounded discrete harmonic spectrum, wherein every its harmonic belongs to the symmetric set $[-m-n,m+n].$
I,e., the nesessary condition of the appearance of the final zero harmonic and unzero result is $\;k \in [-m-n,m+n],$
which contradicts with the problem restrictions.
The answer is 0.
